# Relativity and observable universe

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Will cosmological horizon "expand" for an observer approaching the speed of light (at least in the direction of observer's motion) ?

Answer (score 0):

The observable universe radius is unique to any given point.

[image]

By moving at all, we shift the center of our unique observable universes, causing the boundaries to shift.

Comment: Is observable universe will always be sphere-shaped?

Comment: That radius length will be correlated to the speed of our motion? (assuming the speed is constant)

Comment: @Shura The radius expands at the speed of light. Your position determines the origin.